# Phone number parser producing undesirable white space

Tags: python

```
phone_number = int(input())
line_number =phone_number % 10000
area_code_prefix = phone_number //10000
area_code =area_code_prefix // 1000
prefix =area_code_prefix % 1000

print('(',area_code,')',prefix,'-',line_number)
```

and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've already tried a few different str.() types to try to solve this and none has helped.

Comment: By default, when you pass multiple arguments to `print`, they will be separated by whitespace. To override this behavior, you may provide a value for `print`'s `sep` keyword argument: `print(..., sep='')`

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply avoid passing multiple arguments to `print` in the first place by  passing a single string: `print(f'({area_code}){prefix}-{line_numer}')`

Comment: Thank you, I'm still learning and this helped! @PaulM.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix: ',' produces a white space

```
phone_number = int(input("Enter phone number"))
line_number =phone_number % 10000
area_code_prefix = phone_number //10000
area_code =area_code_prefix // 1000
prefix =area_code_prefix % 1000

print('('+str(area_code)+')'+str(prefix)+'-'+str(line_number))
```